# Multi implementation of an abstract class in typescript for Angular dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dependency-injection

I have an abstract class and an implementation of it

```
export abstract class IPrint {
    abstract Print(textInput: string): void;
}

export class FilePrint implements IPrint {
    Print(textInput: string): void {
        console.log("File Print");
    }
}
```

Then introduce to Angular DI:

```
  providers:
    [
      { provide: IPrint, useClass: FilePrint }
    ],
```

I can use it like the following :

```
  constructor(private _print: IPrint) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this._print.Print("HI"))
  }
```

Now I want to have multi implementation of IPrint

```
export class ScreenPrint implements IPrint {
    Print(textInput: string): void {
        console.log("Screen Print")
    }
}
```

Then introduce to Angular DI:

```
  providers:
    [
      { provide: IPrint, useClass: FilePrint },
      { provide: IPrint, useClass: ScreenPrint }
    ],
```

When I want to use IPrint, angular does not know which implementation must use :

```
constructor(private _print: IPrint) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problematic and solve it by having an interface and a list of InjectionToken. That's a bit overkill, but that's allow a lot of flexibility and can by apply to other issues.

In a project, we setup a global print service in a shared module and multiple custom implementation provided by each component. And that without having to explicitly inject (so reference) all possible implementation in global service.

> Interface and first implementation

```
export interface IPrint {
    Print(textInput: string): void;
}

export class FilePrint implements IPrint {
    Print(textInput: string): void {
        console.log("File Print");
    }
}
```

> Create list of service implementation with InjectionToken

```
 // Keep list of token, provider will give a implementation for each of them
 export const PrintServiceTokens: Map<string, InjectionToken<IPrint>> = new Map();
 // Add File service implementation token
 PrintServiceTokens.set('file', new InjectionToken<IPrint>('file'));
```

> Provider File service implementation

```
   providers: [
      ...
      // First implementation service
      {
         provide: PrintServiceTokens.get('file'),
         useClass: FilePrint
      }
   ]
```

> Other implementation (could be on another module)

```
export class ScreenPrint implements IPrint {
    Print(textInput: string): void {
        console.log("ScreenPrint");
    }
}
```

> Add token for other implementation

```
PrintServiceTokens.set('screen', new InjectionToken<IPrint>('screen'));
```

> Add provider

```
   providers: [
      ...
      // Other implementation service
      {
         provide: PrintServiceTokens.get('screen'),
         useClass: ScreenPrint
      }
   ]
```

> Finally, in a component or service

```
    myPrintService: IPrint;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
       // Up to you to choose service to use, a simple string could be provided by a @Input
       this.myPrintService = this.injector.get(PrintServiceTokens.get('file'));
       this.myPrintService = this.injector.get(PrintServiceTokens.get('screen'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> angular does not know which implementation must use :

angular knows. Angular will use `ScreenPrint`. You just override the injection token for IPrint. You can not have different implementations at a time for **one** injection-token.